# Pull a line from a file and then delete it

Tags: python

I am trying to make a url email crawler. I want to pull a line from a text file, use it once and delete it.

Here is my code.

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    print first_line

with open('urls.txt' , 'w') as file:    
    file.write("0")
```

I an new here and I realize my code looks funny and I'm not sure why.

This is for an email scraping script I found online. It is set to enter the urls as rawdata. I want it to take the first line from a txt file that will include the urls and delete after each use and continue to run the script until the list is empty.

[code]
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import sys
import urllib2
import re

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
   first_line = f.readline()

def getAddress():
    url = raw_input('What Site?')
    http = "http://"
    https = "https://"

    if http in url:
    return url
    elif https in url:
        return url
     else:
        url = "http://" + url
        return url

def parseAddress():
    try:
        website = urllib2.urlopen(getAddress())
        html = website.read()

        addys = re.findall('''[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-    9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?''', html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    print addys

except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
    print "Cannot retrieve URL: HTTP Error Code: ", err.code
except urllib2.URLError, err:
    print "Cannot retrive URL: " + err.reason[1]

def execute():
    parseAddress()

### MAIN

def main():
    execute()

main()
```

Comment: why do you want to delete the line? It's a heavy operation on a file. There may be a better way to achieve your goals

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: In the edited question you read a line from a file but never use it? You seem to use `raw_input` instead? Additionally, your edited code isn't correctly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it;

```
# Read the file as a list of strings, each string is a line.
with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Delete the first line.
del lines[0]

# Write the rest back to the file.
with open('urls.txt' , 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

**Edit**: Given your expanded question, you seem to want to iterate over a list of URLs? If I understood this correctly, a better way to do it would be:

```
# Read the file as a list of strings, each string is a line.
with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Add http:// if necessary:
lines = ['http://'+ln if not ln.startswith('http://') else ln for ln in lines]

# loop over all the URLs
for url in lines:
    parseAddress(url)
```

Comment: this is deleting all lines of the txt file and adding a 0 on line 1.

Comment: @curphey It is true that this overwrites the file: that is how files work. As for the 0, I suggest that you look at what the [del statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) does. In this case it deletes the first string from the list of strings that is called `lines`.